# Jbehave thucydides.. BDD for Java.. examples?

Tags: junit4, jbehave, thucydides

Does anyone know of any good examples of using JBheave and thucydides, to write Acceptance tests for java classes. I have found some tutorials for testing web pages, but i want to know how to write tests for java classes. Using JUNIT.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT's not very clear if you want jBehave or junit examples. There are Maven archetypes for both jBehave and junit available. You can also check out the official documentation - http://www.wakaleo.com/thucydides-one-page/